# Input type date, como formatar saída

Tags: javascript, html

Existe alguma maneira, utilizando apenas atributos HTML de formatar um `<input>` para receber data formatada para `ano/mês/dia`?

Caso não exista em HTML existe alguma forma de fazer isto via Javascript na hora da seleção da data sem utilizar o evento `onblur`?

Comment: A pergunta não está muito clara para mim? pode explicar melhor e juntar um exemplo do que pretende?

Comment: Amigo, vou tex explicar melhor, quando eu coloco input type="date" no html ele mostra o datepicker para mim certo? só que o formato da data quando você clica em alguma data dd/mm/aaaa, eu queria alterar ele para aaaa/mm/dd

Comment: Ok, e quando precisa do valor? tem algum form-submit ou você vai buscar o valor com javascript?

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta para todos entenderem melhor. Editada, ela fica mais completa e as chances de receber uma boa resposta aumentam

Comment: EU já expliquei ao máximo como dava, quero formatar um campo de data no HTML com uma saida diferente de dd/mm/aaaa, ele sera submetido e gravado atraves de um form

Comment: Então agora, edite a pergunta com as novas informações que você colocou nos comentários. Nem todo mundo lê comentários.

Comment: @Alexander, já usou o datepicker do javascript? Ele é mágico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diferentes browsers mostram a data de maneiras diferentes. O Chrome por exemplo usa o formato do seu país/local para formatar a data. Porém, à parte desta diferença visual, a data que é enviada é a mesma. Assim se voçê quer garantir que tem o formato que deseja então sugiro usar JavaScript.

Se tem um form que tem de ser enviado, sugiro criar um `input type="hidden"` escondido que recebe o valor do datepicker no formato que você quer.

Sugestão:

HTML

```
<form action="">
    <input type="date" />
    <input id="formatedDate" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

JavaScript / jQuery

```
function convertDate(inputFormat) {
    function pad(s) {
        return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s;
    }
    var d = new Date(inputFormat);
    return [
        pad(d.getFullYear()), 
        pad(d.getMonth() + 1), 
        d.getDate()
    ].join('/');
}
$('input').on('change', function () {
    $('#formatedDate').val(convertDate(this.value));
});
```

Note que nem todos os browsers suportam o input type="date" / HTML5. Se estiver a usar um outro datepicker então pode usar a função em cima. Caso o datepicker use timestamp unix (commum do lado do servidor), nesse caso deve usar `convertDate(this.value * 1000)`

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o Plugin [jqMask](https://github.com/henriquegogo/jqmask)

Para utiliza-lo apenas inclua o arquivo **jqmask.js** em sua página e depois utilize da seguinte maneira:

```js
$('#ID_Do_Seu_Input').('99/99/9999');
```